# How do I reference a join table with multi-word models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

This may be a stupid question but I can't seem to get it working:

Usually the join table, say between Users and Groups can be accessed like so:

```
GroupsUsers.find(:all)
```

But what if one of the two models has multiple words, say Users and Friend Groups? This does NOT work:

```
FriendGroupsUsers.find(:all)
```

I've tried the below and NONE of them work:

```
FriendGroupsUsers.find(:all)
FriendgroupsUsers.find(:all)
FriendGroups_Users.find(:all)
Friend_GroupsUsers.find(:all)
```

Comment: `FriendsGroupUsers.find(:all)`?

Comment: Show the actual models please

Comment: Oh hmm looks like I never made the actual model, just the database modifications. Thanks for pointing that out...

Comment: You are not supposed to create models for has_and_belongs_to_many join tables. So don't expect one to exist :) (I know this is not a has_many :through because those join tables create a singular model, like expected)

Comment: but how else would I get the above working?

Answer (score -1):

Just create model for your join table, if you dont like standard join model name, than assign any name you want:

```
class AnyName < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name :friends_group_users
end
```

Comment: Not really a solution. The original problem is in the fact that he is trying to access a model that does not exist, assuming a HABTM table automatically has a model associated with it.

Comment: You are right, that was the reason i suggest him to create model for his join table. We also don't know if he using HABTM, so you can be that sure.